# Problem with LINQ to SQL not updating db

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I've read through the posts here and can't find any eureka answers so here's what I have.
Linq to SQl not propagating a change back to the db.

Here's my code. Does anything stand out?
The call to dc.GetChangeSet shows 0 changes. 
What am I missing? I can see the new values from "setting" being set to the cs object properties. SettingID is a primary key in my table and shows as PK in the dbml so that's not an issue.

```
Public Shared Function Update(ByVal setting As ClarifireSetup) As Boolean

    Dim cs As ClarifireSetup

    Try
        Using dc As New AdminClarifireSetupDataContext(TripleDESSecurity.Decrypt(SharedData.PortalCnx))
            cs = (From d In dc.AdminClarifireSetups
                  Where d.SettingID = setting.SettingID
                  Select New ClarifireSetup With {
                    .SettingID = d.SettingID,
                    .SettingKey = d.SettingKey,
                    .SettingValue = d.SettingValue,
                    .FriendlyName = d.FriendlyName,
                    .DisplayOrder = d.DisplayOrder
               }).FirstOrDefault()

            If cs IsNot Nothing Then
                cs.SettingID = setting.SettingID
                cs.SettingKey = setting.SettingKey
                cs.SettingValue = setting.SettingValue
                cs.FriendlyName = setting.FriendlyName
                cs.DisplayOrder = setting.DisplayOrder
                dc.GetChangeSet()
                dc.SubmitChanges()
            End If
        End Using

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        If Not cs Is Nothing Then
            cs.Dispose()
            cs = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

End Function
```

Edit:
Changed my code to this, InsertOnSubmit shows 1 Insert, upon dc.SubmitChanges it errors due to cconflict. It's trying to insert, not update...

```
Public Shared Function Update(ByVal setting As ClarifireSetup) As Boolean

    Dim cs As AdminClarifireSetup

    Try
        Using dc As New AdminClarifireSetupDataContext(TripleDESSecurity.Decrypt(SharedData.PortalCnx))
            'cs = (From d In dc.AdminClarifireSetups
            '      Where d.SettingID = setting.SettingID
            '      Select New AdminClarifireSetup With {
            '        .SettingID = d.SettingID,
            '        .SettingKey = d.SettingKey,
            '        .SettingValue = d.SettingValue,
            '        .FriendlyName = d.FriendlyName,
            '        .DisplayOrder = d.DisplayOrder
            '   }).FirstOrDefault()
            cs = New AdminClarifireSetup

            If cs IsNot Nothing Then
                cs.SettingID = setting.SettingID
                cs.SettingKey = setting.SettingKey
                cs.SettingValue = setting.SettingValue
                cs.FriendlyName = setting.FriendlyName
                cs.DisplayOrder = setting.DisplayOrder
                dc.SubmitChanges()
            End If
        End Using

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        If Not cs Is Nothing Then
            cs = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: sometimes just recreating your DBML can help

Comment: Nope, recreating dbml from scratch didn't help. Still showing 0 items in GetChangeSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the custom class code and just select d.

```
Dim cs as AdminClarifireSetup ' This looks like the actual object type

Try
        Using dc As New AdminClarifireSetupDataContext(TripleDESSecurity.Decrypt(SharedData.PortalCnx))
            cs = (From d In dc.AdminClarifireSetups
                  Where d.SettingID = setting.SettingID
                  Select d).Single()

            If cs IsNot Nothing Then
                cs.SettingID = setting.SettingID
                cs.SettingKey = setting.SettingKey
                cs.SettingValue = setting.SettingValue
                cs.FriendlyName = setting.FriendlyName
                cs.DisplayOrder = setting.DisplayOrder
                dc.GetChangeSet()
                dc.SubmitChanges()
            End If
        End Using
```

My thinking is that the GetChangeSet is failing because it doesn't see any native objects selected that are registering a change. You aren't changing any names, so there's no need to specify the explicit values that you're narrowing down to.

Comment: The AdminClarifireSetup type is just the definition of the single table in the .dbml file. My Custom class is ClarifireSetup. But it looks like the Single needs to be of object AdminClarifireSetup, the actual table object, in order for SubmitChanges to propogate back to the db

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are missing

```
...
dc.ClarifireSetups.InsertOnSubmit( cs )
dc.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: dc.ClarifireSetups... isn't happy

Comment: the table is called AdminClarifireSetups, my class is called ClarifireSetup
So dc.ClarifireSetup doesn't work because it's not a table. 
InsertOnSubmit needs an entity of table as a parameter, not the class object

Comment: InsertOnSubmit fails, it's trying to insert, not update.. see edited code above

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you were trying to copy from the AdminClarifireSetups to ClarifireSetups since you used new when you selected from it :)

Comment: I was following instruction from Telerik support with the original code... but it didn't work obviously.